# how to mock internal calls (xlwt)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I have a test case like this:

```
@mock.patch('xlwt.Workbook.Workbook.save')
    def test_Generic_send_test_email_address(self, workspace_mock):
        workspace_mock.return_value = None
        oi = OptinInvitesGeneric()
        oi.compute(...)
        self.assert ...
```

The actual method does some processing and saves the result in an excel spreadsheet.

```
class OptinInvitesGeneric(OptinBase):
    def compute(...):
      ...
      wb = excel_tool.write_xls(...)
      wb.save('{0}.xls'.format(category))
```

It seems my mock patch doesn't take over the workbook.save(). What am I missing please?

Comment: Why do you say that not take place? where is your assert that check `save()` mock call? Are you sure that `wb` is a 'xlwt.Workbook.Workbook` instance?

Comment: I debug through it with PyCharm. yeah its definitely not a mock instance.

Comment: Maybe as @Vincent say it is a `xlwt.Workbook` instance instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're trying to patch `xlwt.Workbook.Workbook`, but these two work for me:

```
@patch.object(xlwt.Workbook, 'save', return_value=None)
def test_patch_object(mock):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    assert wb.save() == None

@patch('xlwt.Workbook.save', return_value=None)
def test_patch(mock):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    assert wb.save() == None
```

Comment: I think you can use also `mock.patch` and mock che method definition. The real problem was he mock 'xlwt.Workbook.Workbook` instead of `xlwt.Workbook`.